# Django: Media for Views?

Tags: django, django-media

I know the `Media` class for [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/media/).

I like the simple way to include JS/CSS:

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('pretty.css',)
        }
        js = ('animations.js', 'actions.js')
```

Is there a way to use the `Media`class for class based **views**, too?